# Zooming and Scrolling image in SIlverlight 4

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

How to zoom and scroll selected position canvas image(Zoom Cropping canvasimage)

Answer (score 0):

The **[Deep Zoom](http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/deep-zoom/)** technology from Microsoft will make your day, here is the code **[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645050%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)**.